# Unable to see the fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, sharing

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Hello{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}">
  </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:PageBlock title="Contacts">
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Contacts}" var="con">
       <apex:column value="{!con.name}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!con.Phone}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!con.Title}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Want to create a table but i am unable to see the fields name, LastName, phone, Title and their data, please help.  What is the error?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are you testing with an Account that has Contacts? Do you have permission to see those records and fields?

Answer (score 2):

There are two primary things that i would check for this issue

> 1)Since its standard controller i would check if i am passing id as URL parameter
>
> 2)Field level security for the fields of contacts you mentioning

Comment: i can't completely solve it pls if any one completed it pls post code for me

Answer (score 0):

Like Mohith Said.

- Make sure there is record Id passed from the URL . So if your Page name is "MyVFPage" to display some record you should open a page with the following URL "/apex/MyVFPage?id=ValidAccountRecordId"
- Additionally make sure the record that you are opening has some related Contacts in it. Else it wont display anything.